# Need help using a xslt for-each loop when processing through C# processing

Tags: c#, html, xslt

I have the following XML Data

```
<REPORT_DATA>
  <REPORT_ROW>
    <MILESTONE_EVENT_ID>468459779</MILESTONE_EVENT_ID>
    <MILESTONE_EVENT_TYPE_ID>100117</MILESTONE_EVENT_TYPE_ID>
    <MILESTONE_INSTANCE_ID>1265429952</MILESTONE_INSTANCE_ID>
    <EVENT_DESCRIPTION>Trip Released</EVENT_DESCRIPTION>
    <EVENT_DATETIME>2017-10-26T10:36:13.503-04:00</EVENT_DATETIME>
    <TMS_ENTITY_ID>109879262</TMS_ENTITY_ID>
    <TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_ID>100001</TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_ID>
    <TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_DESCRIPTION>Trip Instance</TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_DESCRIPTION>
    <TRIP_INSTANCE_ID>109879262</TRIP_INSTANCE_ID>
    <ROUTE_ID_NUMBER>PERSADDR</ROUTE_ID_NUMBER>
    <CARRIER_SCAC>XXXX</CARRIER_SCAC>
    <CARRIER_NAME>Generic Service Provider</CARRIER_NAME>
    <SCHED_START_DATETIME>2017-09-04T08:00:00-04:00</SCHED_START_DATETIME>
    <SCHED_END_DATETIME>2017-09-05T17:00:00-04:00</SCHED_END_DATETIME>
    <STOP_NUMBER>1</STOP_NUMBER>
    <STOP_ALIAS>3BRW011</STOP_ALIAS>
    <STOP_NAME>Brightwood - Madras</STOP_NAME>
    <STOP_ADDRESS1>335 NW HESS ST</STOP_ADDRESS1>
    <STOP_CITY>MADRAS</STOP_CITY>
    <STOP_STATE>OR</STOP_STATE>
    <STOP_POSTAL_CODE>97741</STOP_POSTAL_CODE>
    <STOP_COUNTRY_CODE>USA</STOP_COUNTRY_CODE>
    <STOP_COUNTRY_NAME>UNITED STATES</STOP_COUNTRY_NAME>
    <SCHED_ARRV_DATETIME>2017-09-04T08:00:00-04:00</SCHED_ARRV_DATETIME>
    <SCHED_DEPART_DATETIME>2017-09-04T09:00:00-04:00</SCHED_DEPART_DATETIME>
    <ACTUAL_ARRV_DATETIME>2017-10-26T11:42:21-04:00</ACTUAL_ARRV_DATETIME>
    <STOP_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID>391604494</STOP_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID>
    <TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_STOPS>2</TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_STOPS>
  </REPORT_ROW>
  <REPORT_ROW>
    <MILESTONE_EVENT_ID>468459779</MILESTONE_EVENT_ID>
    <MILESTONE_EVENT_TYPE_ID>100117</MILESTONE_EVENT_TYPE_ID>
    <MILESTONE_INSTANCE_ID>1265429952</MILESTONE_INSTANCE_ID>
    <EVENT_DESCRIPTION>Trip Released</EVENT_DESCRIPTION>
    <EVENT_DATETIME>2017-10-26T10:36:13.503-04:00</EVENT_DATETIME>
    <TMS_ENTITY_ID>109879262</TMS_ENTITY_ID>
    <TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_ID>100001</TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_ID>
    <TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_DESCRIPTION>Trip Instance</TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_DESCRIPTION>
    <TRIP_INSTANCE_ID>109879262</TRIP_INSTANCE_ID>
    <ROUTE_ID_NUMBER>PERSADDR</ROUTE_ID_NUMBER>
    <CARRIER_SCAC>XXXX</CARRIER_SCAC>
    <CARRIER_NAME>Generic Service Provider</CARRIER_NAME>
    <SCHED_START_DATETIME>2017-09-04T08:00:00-04:00</SCHED_START_DATETIME>
    <SCHED_END_DATETIME>2017-09-05T17:00:00-04:00</SCHED_END_DATETIME>
    <STOP_NUMBER>2</STOP_NUMBER>
    <STOP_ALIAS>PERSADDR</STOP_ALIAS>
    <STOP_NAME>MENOMONIE NORTH</STOP_NAME>
    <STOP_ADDRESS1>5105 FREITAG DRIVE</STOP_ADDRESS1>
    <STOP_CITY>MENOMONIE</STOP_CITY>
    <STOP_STATE>WI</STOP_STATE>
    <STOP_POSTAL_CODE>54751</STOP_POSTAL_CODE>
    <STOP_COUNTRY_CODE>USA</STOP_COUNTRY_CODE>
    <STOP_COUNTRY_NAME>UNITED STATES</STOP_COUNTRY_NAME>
    <SCHED_ARRV_DATETIME>2017-09-05T16:00:00-04:00</SCHED_ARRV_DATETIME>
    <SCHED_DEPART_DATETIME>2017-09-05T17:00:00-04:00</SCHED_DEPART_DATETIME>
    <STOP_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID>391604495</STOP_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID>
    <TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_STOPS>2</TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_STOPS>
   </REPORT_ROW>
</REPORT_DATA
```

And I have the Following XSLT transform

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:usr="urn:the-xml-files:xslt" >
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <title>Delivery Confirmation: </title>

        <style>

          body {
          color: #000000;
          font-family: 'Segoe UI', tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 9pt;
          }

          .heading {
          color: #000000;
          font-family: 'Segoe UI', tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 16pt;
          font-weight: bold;
          }

          .black {
          color: #ffffff;
          font-family: 'Segoe UI', tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 9pt;
          font-weight: bold;
          background-color: black;
          }

          .orange {
          color: #ffffff;
          font-family: 'Segoe UI', tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 9pt;
          font-weight: bold;
          background-color: #cf7317;
          }

          .Text {
          color: #000000;
          font-family: 'Segoe UI', tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 11pt;
          }

          .TextLine {
          color: #000000;
          font-family: 'Segoe UI', tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 11pt;
          font-style: italic;
          }

          .tdBody {
          border: 1px solid black;
          color: #000000;
          font-family: 'Segoe UI', tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 12pt;
          }

        </style>

      </HEAD>
      <body>

        <span class="heading">

          Your have subscribed to receive Trip Updates triggered by the following Event:
        </span>

        <table style="width:60%; border: 1px solid black" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody" width="30%" nowrap="">
              TMS Entity Level
            </td>

            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              TMS Entity ID
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              Event Description
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              Event Date/Time
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//TMS_ENTITY_TYPE_DESCRIPTION"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//TMS_ENTITY_ID"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//EVENT_DESCRIPTION"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//EVENT_DATETIME"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>

        <br />
        <br />

        <span class="heading">
          Trip Details
        </span>

        <br />
        <br />

        <table style="width:60%; border: 1px solid black" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody" width="30%" nowrap="">
              Trip ID
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody" width="30%" nowrap="">
              Scheduled Start
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody" width="30%" nowrap="">
              Scheduled End
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody" width="30%" nowrap="">
              Carrier SCAC
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody" width="30%" nowrap="">
              Carrier Name
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody" width="30%" nowrap="">
              Carrier Pro Number
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//TRIP_INSTANCE_ID"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//SCHED_START_DATETIME"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//SCHED_END_DATETIME"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//CARRIER_SCAC"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//CARRIER_NAME"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="tdBody">
              <xsl:value-of select="//CARRIER_PRO_NUMBER"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <br />
        <span class="TextLine">
          Your subscribed trip has the following
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="//TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_STOPS"/>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          stops:
        </span>

        <br />

        <xsl:for-each select="REPORT_DATA/REPORT_ROW">
            <table style="width:100%; border: 1px solid black" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
              <tr class="orange" style="height:30px;font-size:10pt">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <xsl:text>Stop </xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_NUMBER"/>
                  <xsl:text> Of </xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_STOPS"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                <td>
                  <xsl:text>Stop ID: </xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_DETAIL_INSTANCE_ID" />
                </td>
                <td class="tdBody">
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_NAME" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="not(SCHED_ARRV_DATETIME)">
                    <td>
                      <xsl:text>Sched Arrival: </xsl:text>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:text>Sched Arrival: </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="SCHED_ARRV_DATETIME" />
                    </td>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <td class="tdBody">
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_ADDRESS1" />
                  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_ADDRESS2" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="not(SCHED_DEPART_DATETIME)">
                    <td>
                      <xsl:text>Sched Depart: </xsl:text>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:text>Sched Depart: </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="SCHED_DEPART_DATETIME" />
                    </td>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <td class="tdBody">
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_CITY" />
                  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_STATE" />
                  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_POSTAL_CODE" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="not(ACTUAL_ARRV_DATETIME)">
                    <td>
                      <xsl:text>Actual Arrival: </xsl:text>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:text>Actual Arrival: </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ACTUAL_ARRV_DATETIME" />
                    </td>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <td class="tdBody">
                  <xsl:value-of select="STOP_COUNTRY_CODE" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="not(ACTUAL_DEPART_DATETIME)">
                    <td>
                      <xsl:text>Actual Depart: </xsl:text>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:text>Actual Depart: </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ACTUAL_DEPART_DATETIME" />
                    </td>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </xsl:for-each>

        <br />
        <br />

  <span class="Text">
          For any issues regarding the above trip, please contact: <a href="mailto:support@andersenwindows.com">support@andersenwindows.com</a>

          <br />
          <br />

        </span>

      </body>

      </HTML>
      </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, there's a for-each loop to go through each stop and I have tested the data on the site https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog and it come's out pretty much like I want. However, when I try to use the template in our process, that run's through a C# mid-tier, it basically ignores the for-each loop so, it doesn't show any stops, and just shows the top and bottom of the table such as:

Your subscribed trip has the following 2 stops: 
"the table of the 2 stops is supposed to show here"

For any issues regarding the above trip, please contact: support@andersenwindows.com

Is there something in .Net that I'm missing that doesn't interpret the loop?

Comment: Are you sure your mid-tier application uses the xslt shown and has the shown input data? I cannot think of any reason for the xsl processor to ignore your for-each loop.

Comment: I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything in the xslt or if there's something that .Net does before I had our guys start going stepping through the mid-tier code. It's driving me nuts.We use other xslt transforms, but never used a for-each before

Comment: Got it figured out...on the for-each, it needs to read //REPORT_ROW instead of REPORT_DATA/REPORT_ROW

Answer (score 0):

The for-each has to read //REPORT_ROW instead of REPORT_DATA/REPORT_ROW